Is there a wrapper for function call for std:::generator?
Is there an existing wrapper to call a function for std::generator like in the code below?
Although mine works just fine, I don't won't to reinvent the wheel, since code would be more complex for different signatures of functions.
#include <experimental/generator>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
std::experimental::generator<float> function_generator(T op) {
    while (true)
        co_yield op();
}

constexpr auto gen1 = []() {
    return 1.0f; /* Some generator in real code */
    };

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> v = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f };

    auto gen = function_generator(gen1) | std::views::take(10 - 1);

    v.insert_range(std::next(v.begin()), gen);

    for (auto& val : v) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}

Important notice, I need to insert in the middle of container, so std::generate and back_inserters don't work here.
Is there something which I could use for this purpose (generate a range of inserted objects) without third-party libraries?
If this task (adding a range of generated values) could be done without std::generator, please, advise (of course without adding dummy objects like filling by zeroes and then running std::generate on the added range).

Out of curiosity, which compiler (and version) do you use on your snippet ?

"Although mine works just fine, I don't won't to reinvent the wheel" Do you mean function_generator? This utility doesn't seem to be very complicated to implement.

Even if it doesn't answer the question , this paper  could be of interest.

@edrezen, MSVC latest version with `/std::c++latest' compiler key.

C++ doesn't have an out-of-the-box wrapper specifically tailored to convert callable functions into std::generator-like objects...you can achieve the desired functionality using std::generate_n, which is straightforward for generating a range of objects from a callable
#include <experimental/generator>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

// Template for generator
template <typename T>
std::experimental::generator<float> function_generator(T op) {
    while (true)
        co_yield op();
}

// Your generator logic
constexpr auto gen1 = []() {
    return 1.0f; // Replace with your actual logic
};

int main() {
    std::vector<float> v = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f };

    // Create the generator and limit its output to 9 values
    auto gen = function_generator(gen1) | std::views::take(9);

    // Insert the generated range into the middle of the vector
    auto insert_pos = std::next(v.begin()); // Insert after the first element
    v.insert(insert_pos, gen.begin(), gen.end());

    // Output the modified vector
    for (const auto& val : v) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Thank you for your input. I am sorry, I was sure that I stressed the point that I need to insert in the middle of the std::vector. I missed this part of text somehow. I've added the "Important notice, I need to insert in the middle of container, so std::generate and back_inserters don't work here." comment and updated the code sample. My apologies again.

@DamirTenishev You can change the back_inserter into a inserter: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter

With help from @NathanOliver (many thanks to him) it woks like a charm. If you update your answer to use std::inserter, I'd like to accept it (just to avoid confusing other readers, accepting current version which doesn't compile: demo). I would use the following one: demo, but it is a matter of your choice, of course, just wanted to save you some time.
